# TestNG не запускает все тесты из сьюта

Tags: java, testng

Задача: есть тест который раскинут по 87 тестовым классам и это всё дело необходимо собрать в сьют.

Что я сделал: Вкинул в каждый из 87 тестов атрибут группы и её название, после создал xml сьют, вкинул туда название группы и тестовые классы в которых лежит этот тест.

Что происходит: тестнг успешно запускает 46 из 87 тестов, после этого без всяких ошибок и эксцепшенов останавливается, в тултип рана выводит "прошло 46, не удалось запустить 41" и всё на этом.

Что попробовал сделать: сделать сьют сьютов, эффект есть но кривой. всё равно все 87 не запускает, НО чем больше плодишь сютов (на данный момент 6 в 1), то тестнг запускает большее количество тестов из общего числа(на данный момент 72 из 87).
Так же попробовал поиграть с объёмом выделяемой памяти для этого дела в конфигах сьюта (vm options) - не помогло.
В гугле тоже ничего толкового найти не могу.

Вопрос: что происходит??? Может кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой??

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена параллелизацией сьюта. Но истиная причина не известна.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).